# Run command after any non SIGSTOP signal

Tags: bash

I want to run `bar` after `foo`, but only if `bar` wasn't sent SIGSTOP. How can I accomplish this, without running a subshell?

For example, say I'm running `emacs`, and want to `echo 'goodbye'` after it exits. If I simply do `emacs; echo 'boodbye'` then CTRL-Z will do the echo. But I only want `goodbye` to be echoed when the `emacs` process is stopped in anyway, including normally exiting `emacs`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html). That is, doing something like `( emacs; echo 'goodbye' )`.

While this does use a subshell, I was previously tricked that `$(...)` is using command substitution + a subshell which led me to believe that the subshell was reason for disallowing CTRL-Z, not the substitution.

Comment: i wonder if chaining with `&&` or `||` would be better than `;` -- but you'd want to ensure that any return value triggered the final `echo`, so `emacs && echo 'foo'` isn't quite right.  `emacs || echo -n "" && echo 'foo'` might work. (the first echo just outputs an empty string to ensure the post-`&&` command triggers, no matter what `emacs` returns.)